# ns create cannot create a working project

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

I do the following:

```sh
ns create HelloNg --template @nativescript/template-tab-navigation-ng
ns create BlankNg --template @nativescript/template-blank-ng
ns create Blank --template @nativescript/template-blank
ns create Create
# allways finished with:
Project xyz was successfully created.
# after change the working directory to the project folder, i try to run/debug
ns run android
ns debug android
```

I have allways the same error: `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')`

`ns doctor android` output is: No issues were detected.

System: Ubuntu 20.04

NativeScript 8.2.2

npm 8.3.1

node v16.14.0

What can i do?

[edit]

```sh
$ ns clean
⠋ Cleaning project...
✔ Cleaned directory hooks
ℹ Skipping platforms because it doesn't exist.
✔ Cleaned directory node_modules
✔ Cleaned file package-lock.json
✔ Project successfully cleaned.
$ ns run android
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')
$ tns platform add android
Copying template files...
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'latest')
$ ns run android
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')
$ ns clean
⠋ Cleaning project...
ℹ Skipping hooks because it doesn't exist.
✔ Cleaned directory platforms
ℹ Skipping node_modules because it doesn't exist.
ℹ Skipping package-lock.json because it doesn't exist.
✔ Project successfully cleaned.
```

[edit]

Now with `--log trace`

```sh
$ ns debug android --log trace
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')
    at Object.maxSatisfying (/usr/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/semver/ranges/max-satisfying.js:13:12)
    at PackageInstallationManager.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/package-installation-manager.js:56:27)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/usr/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/package-installation-manager.js:5:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the mistake. Node.js was installed as a snap package. This caused problems with various tools.

Now Node.js is installed in my home directory from node.tar.xz and everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')
```

This error sounds like something from your own code. You are using a forEach some where and the object is null. You can see excact line number if you go further up in the console log.

Comment: there is nothing from me ...only the created project.

Comment: Could you post the stracktrace? Should be more details of where that error happens

Comment: There is no stacktrace. If i run the command `ns debug android` then comes only the line `Cannot read properties of null (reading 'forEach')`.

Comment: If you run: ns clean && ns run android You should get more then one line in your console

Comment: Try adding the `--log trace` flag